# IE7 text align issue

Tags: html, css

http://wilwaldon.com/ie7sucks/

If you view this page in anything but IE7 you will see that the spotlight area text is displayed in a column on the right of the image.

For some reason it's not showing as a column and I have no idea why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I'd owe you my first born.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Saying that IE7 sucks is not the way. You have to compensate for the differences in all browsers which is something that all web designers struggle with. Write your CSS correctly and this shouldn't be an issue. (I do not know how to do that however:()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the developer tools if I got rid of the width: 100% from .onecolumnright P it fixed the problem.  Though I'm looking at it using IE 8 in compatibility mode.

Comment: Works perfect. What's up with IE7 and width problems? THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

You've got some CSS that isn't supported by IE7 (and earlier):

```
.spotlightbox p { display: table-cell; }
```

Try replacing that with this, and tweak the width as you like:

```
.spotlightbox p { width: 160px; }
```

I tested this at [Adobe BrowserLab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/) in Internet Explorer 7.0 and it seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

yeah pressing f12 is a huge help with IE;

```
.onecolumnright p{
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 50%;
}
```